# Can I make QGIS export one thing at the time?

Tags: qgis, raster, export, parallel-processing

While I am exporting a large amounts of TIFF files for my work, I am having a small bottleneck in my workflow. Up until now I have devided the TIFF images in smaller pieces so that my computer can process them (a project can contain 16 GeoTIFF images or more). The exports go well one by one, however to keep productive on a larger scale during the day. I like to export all the pieces at once, and put them in a the waiting list to export. This means I can focus on other work for a few hours and come back when the pc finishes running. However at the moment there are multiple files being exported at the time. Example 5 files being exported and the rest of the 16 are in the queue.
However I notice that my PC runs hot, and finds it hard to export more then one file at the time.

Is there a way to change the waitnglist settings in QGIS to that only one file is processed at the time, and the rest is in the waiting list?

Technical details:
Using version 3.4 of QGIS, on a Windows pc.
Also I am not a coder.

Comment: What are your Windows Specs (RAM, etc) and how big are your 16 geotiffs?.

Comment: 16 GB of Ram, i7 core chip. So specs are not that bad. 
Sometimes the TIFF files can get up to 15 to 25 GB. My system has no problem processing the files one by one. However I am trying to find out if there is a way to manage the queue. (the little blue bar below) so that it only does one export at the time. So I can leave my pc running and do the 16 parts in one time. 

p.s. Vince thanks for correcting my English 
I am not a native speaker, so hope you will excuse my grammar errors.

Comment: use a batch of an algorythm or a model. This way the process is sequential instead of parallel.